# Get the next_available_ip from an Infoblox WAPI server using a dynamic network search, via REST

Tags: infoblox

I have a collection of *network* objects in my Infoblox (IPAM) server and would like to allocate an IP address from one of them based on a search into their *extattr* fields.

Each *network* object has an extended attribute named *CITYCODE*, and many networks have the same value for that code. I want to allocate an IP address from any of those networks.

How can I use the next_available_ip function to create a *record:host* object, where the *IPV4ADDR* is determined by the next_available_ip function?

Comment: I removed the python tag because AFAICT there is no python anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question because it took some poking with other example code I found to get one that worked exactly right for me.

First you need a JSON body that specifies the fully qualified *name* of the new *record:host*. For my purposes I'm just generating random values. Note, that the domain must already exist (likely as a *zone:auth* object).

If the domain does not already exist you'll get the error: "The action is not allowed. A parent was not found."

Instead of specifying an actual *ipv4addr*, instead specify the target object and the function you will run against it. Since we want to run the next_available_ip function, the object is *network*.

The search we want to do is against an extensible attribute, so the _object_parameters are set to say "find networks that have an extensible attribute called -CITYCODE- with value -MZAPPKAK-. The asterisk is important and must be kept.

```
BODY='
{
    "name" : "staticip-d4260ed7-3101-4034-0f79-056b72b2c5f0.some-domain-that-exists.com",
    "ipv4addrs : [
        {
            "ipv4addr" : {
                "_object" : "network",
                "_object_function" : "next_available_ip",
                "_object_parameters" : {"*CITYCODE" : "MZAPPKAK"},
                "_object_field" : "value",
                "_result_field" : "ips",
                "_parameters" : {"num" : 1}
            }
        }
    ]
}

curl \
    'https://1.2.3.4/wapi/v2.2.1/record:host' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d "$BODY"
```

The result code should be 201, and the result body will be a REF to the *record:host* that was created. Do a standard GET on the returned REF to learn what IP was found and placed on the record.